# Changing YYYYMMDD to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: excel

So I have a date that is 20170529 but whenever I try to format it to a date, the cell just becomes #########. So normally, that means the column width is too small, but even when I extend the column, it just shows #####

How do I convert these to dates.

Comment: I suppose this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37611179/5513005) might help you

Comment: Thanks, I used =DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))

Answer (score 2):

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"0000\/00\/00"))
```

and format the result as a date

Answer (score 2):

A quick method would be Data, Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Date: YMD, Finish. The following is for all intents and purposes in real-time.

[image]

Shouldn't take too much to record that into a sub procedure.

Answer (score 1):

from format cell choose from category choose date and choose which type you want

Comment: That will work if and only if the value stored is a real date value formatted to display as yyyymmdd.  In other words, your method will NOT work if the value stored is `20170529`.  It will work only if the value stored is `42884`

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to fix and run this short macro:

```
Sub INeedADate()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        If Len(v) = 8 Then
            r.Clear
            r.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            r.Value = DateSerial(Left(v, 4), Mid(v, 5, 2), Right(v, 2))
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: His tags do not include `vb`. I think he's asking the question as in for purely MS-Excel use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used "Gary's Student's" answer. You have to press ALT+F11 and just copy and paste, then close that window. Then you select the cells you want to change, go to VIEW tab, on the far right is macros, hit view macros and select the one that says "INeedADate"