# Change Excel data

Tags: excel

I have Excel doc that contains date column, but it was writtn as `19920504`
the real date is `04-05-1992`
is there any method or formula to fix it? (rather than manully because I have huge data)

Comment: What is the format of the initial data? Text, number, date???

Comment: I didn't create that file, but when I make a new file it gives me the same result.

Comment: Easy to fix................is the "real" date **April 5** or **May 4** ??

Comment: Thanks you all, it worked for me now. I found the answer in the link, next answer.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247877/changing-yyyymmdd-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the column with the dates in it and go to Data | Text to Columns. Skip the first couple of screens, and in the next screen set the date format to YMD.

Answer (score 3):

If H5 contains 19920504 then this formula returns an Excel date: (in the UK it returns 04/05/1992 )

```
=DATE(LEFT(H5,4),MID(H5,5,2),RIGHT(H5,2))
```