# Change Date Format in Excel from mm-dd-yy hh:mm to dd-mm-yy hh:mm

Tags: excel

I am exporting data from an external source.
It has a date format as `mm-dd-yy hh:mm`. Post pasting it in Excel the format shows as `General`.
How can I convert it to `dd-mm-yy hh:mm`?

Comment: Have already tried custom format ddmmyy hh:mm but no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change date format of cell in excel from dd.mm.yyyy to yyy/mm/dd ( excel version 2013 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609401/change-date-format-of-cell-in-excel-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyy-mm-dd-excel-version)

Comment: **Import** it into Excel using `Power Query`.  Select to Transform and change the format of that column to `Date-->using Locale` and select a compatible locale for that format -- i.e. English - United States.  When you save it to your worksheet, it will be a "real" date-time and you can format it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If the cell will not change format, it may be a text string.  Try using;

```
=DATE(2000+MID(A1,7,2),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2)) + TIME(MID(A1,10,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)
```

and set the proper formmat:

[image]